# Remove-AzureRmStorageAccount with -Force failing

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, octopus-deploy

I am trying to run following powershell script through Octopus

```
$ResourceGroupName = "#{ResourceGroupName}"
$StorageAccountName = "#{ScriptStorageAccount}"
# Remove storage account 
Remove-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -AccountName $StorageAccountName -Force
```

Which works from my laptop But fails on Octopus server, with following error

```
20:49:51   Verbose  |       Invoking target script "C:\Octopus\Work\20170206204944-14912\scripts\post-deployement.ps1" with  parameters
20:49:54   Error    |       Invoke-Expression : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
20:49:54   Error    |       'Force'.
20:49:54   Error    |       At C:\Octopus\Work\20170206204944-14912\scripts\Octopus.AzureContext.ps1:99
20:49:54   Error    |       char:5
20:49:54   Error    |       +     Invoke-Expression ". $OctopusAzureTargetScript $OctopusAzureTarge ...
20:49:54   Error    |       +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
20:49:54   Error    |       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], Parame
20:49:54   Error    |       terBindingException
20:49:54   Error    |       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
20:49:54   Error    |       ands.InvokeExpressionCommand
20:49:54   Fatal    |       The remote script failed with exit code 1
```

I have powershell version (PSVersion : 5.0.10586.117) on octopus (version: 3.7.4)

Comment: Update Azure module on Octopus server?

Comment: What he said.  The specific module you are looking for is: AzureRM.Storage.  Check it on both machines using: get-module AzureRM.Storage

Comment: I upgraded the powershell & storage account is created though same octopus with powershell.